# how to make modal window not close after refetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql

Good day to all. My question is: is it possible to make the modal window not close after the refetch happens?
At the moment, I have implemented the function of launching the broadcast in a modal window and by clicking on the "Start" button, the variable is refetched, which is responsible for whether the broadcast activity is true or false. And after refetch my modal closes, which I don't want. I can provide code if needed, but it seems to me that this is a more generalized problem.

Comment: a code snippet sometimes helps :) so feel free to do it

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of what you want to achieve, what you already tried and what is your current result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By refetch you referring to Refresh of the browser?
If so, I would suggest use some [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) or managing your own storage over [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), on each open/close of the modal, you should update your store/localstorage, and on the next refresh, check if you got modal data stored and open the modal again accordantly.